# Create JS function that copies text and surrounds it in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a Javascript funciton that adds a paragraph tag around the text, and tranforms outputs it as i were (with code)

I've gotten:

```
function texttransfer()
{
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');

newParagraph.textContent = document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(newParagraph);
}

document.getElementById("a").onclick = texttransfer;
```

now all of the `<br/>` tags show up as plain text... how do i remove this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you are setting textContent which is plain text!

Use innerHTML, but if the source element has elements that do not belong in a paragraph (aka [flow elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)), it will have a different output. You want to use a div.

```
newParagraph.innerHTML = document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery (since your post has the jQuery tag) :

```
function textTransfer(){
   $(document).append('<p>'+$("#source").html()+'</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy of the text content too :

```
var oldParagraph = document.getElementById("source")
newParagraph.textContent = oldParagraph.textContent;
```